# DDD Best way to preserve integrity of entity

Tags: domain-driven-design, state, entity, data-integrity

I have an entity that contain the status of data (`WaitingForData`, `ReadyForData`, `DataUsed`).

```
class Batch
{
    int Status { get; }
    DateTime StartTime { get; }
    string Code { get; }
    void SetCode(string code)
    {
       Code=code; 
       if (StartTime not null) { Status = ReadyForData; }
    }
    void SetDate(DateTime date)
    {
       StarDate=date; 
       if (Code not null) { Status = ReadyForData; }
    }
    Product Product { get; }
    Category Category { get; }
}
class Product{...}
class Category{...}
```

When `StartTime` and `Code` are not null, the `Status` move from `WaitingForData` to `ReadyForData`. For preserve the integry of my Entity I check in `SetDate()` and `SetCode` if all data have a value and move the status.

Now my Entity need to change the `Status` for some value of `Product` and `Category` because:

- for some `Category` of `Product`, the status can move to `ReadyForData` when have the `Code` not null (i.e. `StartDate` is ignored),
- for the other combination of `Category` and `Product` still check the `Code` and `StartDate`.

From the point of view of DDD, what is the best way to do?

I think to create the interface `IManageBatch` with method  `CheckStatusData(Product, Category, Batch)` and the method return the status of `Batch`.

So the Batch method change to:

```
void SetCode(string code, IManageBatch checker);
void SetDate(DateTime date, IManageBatch checker);
    {
       StarDate=date; 
       if (checker.CheckStatusData(Product, Category, this)) { Status = ReadyForData; }
    }
```

Is this way is an antipattern? Because my domain is not pure? As alternative, can I move the use of `SetDate()` in an Appplication Service, and after check teh status and update.

```
MethodInApplicationService(string code, IManageBatch checker)
{
    batchEntity.SetCode(code);
    var result = checker(batchEntity.PRoduct, batchEntity.Category, batchEntity);
    if (result)  batchEntity.ChangeStatus(ReadyFroBatch)
}
```

In this way if I forgot to change the status and call only the `SetCode` I have my entity in `WaintingForData` when is Ready, and my entity in an Inconsistent value...

What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Maybe you can create an intermediate class that combines product with category and contains the required knowledge for the batch to make the correct decisions. I would not be surprised that this is a named concept in the domain; talk about it with a domain expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first level for managing integrity is the aggregate:

> **AGGREGATE**: A cluster of associated objects that are treated as **a unit for the purpose of data changes**. External references are restricted to one member of the AGGREGATE, designated as the root. A set of **consistency rules** applies within the AGGREGATE’S boundaries.
>  - Eric Evans in *Domain-Driven Design*

Since `Batch` is associated with `Product` and `Category` of products,  and since these seem to influence its behavior,  it's worth to think if `Batch` should not in reality belong to the `Product` aggregate.

But perhaps your model does not allow to easily group this in a single aggregate. And anyway, the category would probably stay separate.

Another approach would be to leave aggregates as they are, but implement a proper state machine to isolate the rules for change of state.  It would be tempting to see this as a service.  But a service is meant for operations that do not naturally belong to any single aggregate.  The fact that the state update requires to access other aggregates is not sufficient for that, because the state seems to closely belong to the batch. A state pattern can help if the state-dependent behaviors are getting complex.

Another way, would be to go for events. A change of `Code` or of `StartDate` are just events that are relevant for a state change.  Changes of some `Product` or `Category` characteristics are also events.  `Batch` could then subscribe and consume all events relevant for its state change.  The main difference compared to the other approaches, is that the change of state can be decoupled in time, and when the state is updated it's consistend,  but at a given time,  the state can be obsolete. There are other patterns to deal with such situations.   But I have the impression that this might be overkill for your current problem.